# Solving this problem with Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is my question

In a community by $28$ people which occurs by who loves reading a book, listening to music and watching film. Everyone loves listening to music in this community. The value of who loves reading a book is $2$ more people than who loves watching film and who loves three events is just equal to the value of who loves listening to music. So, who loves three events = who loves listening to music (just)

- Then, how many people who love reading a book are there in this community?

I want to solve it with Venn diagram but couldn't draw the diagram. Might I get help for building equations and venn diagram? I'm so stuck.

Regards

Comment: "who loves these three events is only equal to the value of who loves listening to music." ... that's a little hard to understand. As it is, it seems to be saying that the number of people loving all three things equals the number of people who love music .. which implies that there are not any people who, say, love seeing a film but not love music. Indeed, it would imply that everyone in this community loves all three activities, but that goes against there being 2 more people who love reading a book than watching a film. Can you please check your givens and update your post accordingly?

Comment: @Bram28 Who loves three events is just equal to the value of who loves listening to music means who loves three events = who loves listening to music.

Comment: Can someone help If I made it better?

Comment: I see: the number of people liking 3 equals the number of people who *only* love music

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Venn diagram:

[image]

So you know $X + X + Y + Y + 2=28$ and you're trying to find $X + Y + 2$

Comment: I've found $x+y = 13$.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten You bet! And so how many people love reading books?

Comment: Love you man! I've found $15$! This venn diagram is very very helpful.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten Yes, that's it! Yeah, very helpful! :)

Comment: Also I'm sorry If I did too many posts cause my exam :/ I fear it.

Answer (score 0):

Build the standard Venn diagram for three sets. The universe will be divided into eight parts. Since everyone loves music, the parts outside of the music set will $=0$. Label the four remaining parts whatever you like; say $x, y, z, w$ and then take the information given and write it down in terms of $x, y, z, w$. For example, you will have $x+y+z+w=28$.